# How to exclude array of ids from query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have an array of `_ids` and I want to exclude them from the query:

```
console.log('relatedCards', relatedCards);
const motherCards = await db.MotherCard.find({ "_id": { $ne : relatedCards } });
```

But it returns this error:

[image: no]

Why this is happening and how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ ne` is usually used for a value. But if you want to exclude multiple items in `array`, you can use `$ nin`

For example I have this model:

```js
{
  "_id": "5a934e000102030405000000",
  "key": 1
},
{
  "_id": "5a934e000102030405000001",
  "key": 2
},
{
  "_id": "5a934e000102030405000002",
  "key": 3
},
{
  "_id": "5a934e000102030405000003",
  "key": 4
},
{
  "_id": "5a934e000102030405000004",
  "key": 5
}
```

And I want exclude `key:3` and `key5`:

```js
db.collection.find({
key: {
  "$nin": [
    3,
    5
  ]
}
})
```

Now this query return a correct result:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "5a934e000102030405000000",
    "key": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a934e000102030405000001",
    "key": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "5a934e000102030405000003",
    "key": 4
  }
]
```

I hope this solution helps you.

Comment: Does this work for _ids too?